# No more space between flex-items when in column

Tags: css, flexbox

Why isn't there any space left when my flex-items (.first, .second and .third) wrap into a column?
While in a row, they space evenly.

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }

main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-flow: wrap;
    align-items: center;

}

img {
    border: solid;
}

.first {
    flex: 0;
}

.second {
    flex: 0;
}

.third {
    flex: 0;
}
```

```
<main>
    <img class="first" src="images/tronche_webb_25.jpg" alt="tête de yann" />
    <img class="second" src="images/tronche_webb_50.jpg" alt="tête de yann" />
    <img class="third" src="images/tronche_webb_35.jpg" alt="tête de yann" />
</main>
```

Isn't align-content suppose to help?
Thank you.

Comment: Could you please post your HTML code as well?

Comment: Only three img elements.

Comment: Is the CSS code copied correctly? If it's the same in your code as in the question then you have an error in your CSS: there's a missed selector for the `box-sizing: border-box;` rule.

Comment: missed that while editing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define height for the main in order to get justify-content: space-evenly to work.

Try this.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }

main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-flow: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 500px;

}

img {
    border: solid;
}

.first {
    flex: 0;
}

.second {
    flex: 0;
}

.third {
    flex: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
    <img class="first" src="https://placehold.it/100x100/ccc/666?text=" alt="tête de yann" />
    <img class="second" src="https://placehold.it/100x100/ccc/666?text=" alt="tête de yann" />
    <img class="third" src="https://placehold.it/100x100/ccc/666?text=" alt="tête de yann" />
</main>
```

Comment: I've copied and tried your code and it stopped wrapping. What have I done wrong?

Comment: it wraps when I delete flex-direction: column; from your code but the height: 500px has not helped. The images are still touching each other. I know a margin-top would help but I'd like to fix that with flex only.

Comment: My img are larger. I'd like the 3 img to be at the top of the screen and spaced evenly when in row and in column. Now that I've set an height, there's too much space above the pictures when in row. I've edited your code.